# how to set path for django admin to make javascript and css of work on Windows XP and development server

Tags: django, django-admin

I try to execute django (1.4) tutorial admin on windows. But there is not access to css and javascript.
I set in setty.py:

```
# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/'

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My urils:
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

## Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^mysite/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),

```
# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
# url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

)

It still doesn't work. Could you please tell how to solve this issue and what's the best way to solve it?
My proect is in c:\django-projects\mysite.
When I execute admin `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/polls/poll/1/` I can see error of development server:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", l
ine 68, in __call__
    return super(StaticFilesHandler, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 241, i
n __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", l
ine 58, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", l
ine 51, in serve
    return serve(request, self.file_path(request.path), insecure=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\views.py", line
 41, in serve
    return static.serve(request, path, document_root=document_root, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\static.py", line 57, in serve

    mimetype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(fullpath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 294, in guess_type
    init()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 355, in init
    db.read_windows_registry()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 259, in read_windows_registry
    for ctype in enum_types(mimedb):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 249, in enum_types
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal
```

Here is from settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'polls'
)
```

In firebug I get 500 http return code for css and js files and path seems strange to me.
For example:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/admin/css/base.css
```

I tried to added in settings.py:

```
# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    'C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin', //here css and js and img folders for for admin

)
```

And changing urls.py to this one:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^mysite/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

But it still doesn't work.

Django documenation say here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-the-admin-files that: "The admin files live in (django/contrib/admin/static/admin) of the Django distribution.". But it still doesn't wok.

Comment: are you using the manage.py runserver? or other webserver?

Comment: I'm using manage.py runserver.

Comment: did you put all the static files under folder named 'static' inside your django app? and the django app is in the INSTALLED_APPS inside the settings?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Could you please explain what you?

Comment: I edited my question with install apps info.

Comment: I think the files should be in C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static.

Comment: I don't quite understand how STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT works.

Comment: In firebug I get 500 http return code for css and js files and path seems strange to me.
For example:

    http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/admin/css/base.css

Comment: follow steps 1,2,3 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#basic-usage

Comment: I'm talking about about css and js of django admins. It still doesn't work.

Comment: I edited question, addigng what I tried to do.

Comment: It seems step 3 from here doesn't make sense for django admin, right?

Comment: you have encoding issues.. which database are you using? and what language (not english?)

Comment: I use mysql database and utf8.

Comment: delete all your data in the mysql and see if it works.

Comment: Do you mean delete data in all tables or only tables of models?

Comment: I deleted data from tables with models, but there is still this error.

Comment: It looks like the problem with decode error was because of windows registry having here:  "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type"  non-latin names